# azure devops library variables value to be passed to azure datafactory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass the following variables from the azure DevOps library as variables to the data factory pipeline. For some reason, the variables are not populating in the data factory pipeline.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwakl.png)

When I check the pipeline I don't see the variables populated.

So is my understanding correct if we provide variables (eg moris@aix.com, lowes@aix.com, and so on)
will this be populated in the data factory pipeline as a variable too? If yes then I am unable o figure out the reason why is not getting updated with the variables in the data factory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORypt.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the images it seems to me that you are mixing up two types of pipelines:

- Azure DevOps pipelines
- Azure Data Factory pipelines

The first type (Azure DevOps) can be used to deploy an Azure Data Factory resource, and you can include Azure DevOps variable groups. You could then propagate these variables as global variables in the Data Factory and subsequently use them in Data Factory pipeline tasks.

To answer your questions: Yes, it is possible to populate Data Factory pipelines from Azure DevOps variable groups, but it does not happen automatically.

**Edit:** For this use case (Email adresses) I would rather use a parametrized lookup activity in Data Factory, which reads the Email adresses from a .csv-file in a storage account.

Comment: That is very correct if we use global variables, however in this case we have local variables. So is it possible and is it a goo way to pass values to the variables from devops to datafactory? i am don't think its an optimal way to do the need full

Comment: From your image I can see, that your input are email adresses. I would suggest you use a Data Factory lookup task on a csv-file in a storage account. If you have multiple environments, you could store three files (contacts-dev.csv, contacts-int.csv, contacts-prod.csv), and parametrize the filename in the look-up activity.

Comment: Yes this option of lookup i have tried and that's a good one . but here requirement is only to use the devops library variable.

Comment: In this case you could prefix the global variables with the abbreviation of the local environment, i.e. email_dev = ....